# PDF slide viewer "soft of"

Tags: pdf

I am looking for a PDF viewer preferably in Ubuntu (but would settle for Windows if one was available)  This PDF viewer should act like a microfiche viewer...what I mean is I shouldn't have to click on any file names in a folder to view the file...when searching through 1000's of PDF in a folder and you are looking for a specific PDF but the only option to find it is to actually look at the document itself...  Just like when looking through a microfiche machine...
If anyone knows of anything that is close to that... please let me know.
Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds less like something to be done by a PDF viewer. How about enabling thumbnails for pdf in your Filemanager? In Dolphin (the KDE default file manager) you can do this by executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt install kdegraphics-thumbnailers
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plugins/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/
```

and then going to configure Dolphin --> General--> Preview and enabling for pdf.

I am confident that it is as easy in Nautilus.

Another alternative might be organizing your pdf library in [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). Calibre will create a thumbnail from the first page of each pdf file (like a filemanager would do too).